# apply css to the jquery mobile element inside a page

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to build an app using jquery mobile. Below is the structure of the html doc. I'd like apply styling to the internal elements of the content. I'd like to apply the css to the "< pre>" elements using and relative stylesheet defined in a separate .css page. How do I achieve this?

Thanks,

Arun

```
<div data-role="page" id="myid">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>My header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<pre> page content............</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add classes to the elements so you can access them correctly.

```
<div data-role="page" id="myid">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>My header</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
<pre class="target"> page content............</pre>
</div>
</div>
```

Then target them

```
$(".target").css("color", "red" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do:

```
$("pre").addClass("myClass");
```

You can also add a CSS class to `pre` and select it:

```
<pre class="preClass">
....
$(".preClass").addClass("myClass");
```

Or you can add an ID to `pre` and select it

```
<pre id="preID">
....
$("#preID").addClass("myClass");
```

Some ways to select elements are:

1. $(".myClass") - selecting by class
2. $("#myID")
3. $("*") - select all elements

`addClass` is used to add one or more CSS class to the selected elements.

More information on selectors are available at:

[JQuery Selectors - jquery.com](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

[JQuery Selectors - w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Comment: is it not possible to use the external css file for styling instead of jquery. 

a

Comment: I just tried to change it through jquery but it isn't working. 

https://jsbin.com/dunowow/edit?html,console,output

Comment: In the example you have attached, the style is applied to all `pre` elements. No jquery is required to do that. What exactly are you trying to do ?